# Core Data Encryption Class

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, encryption, sqlcipher

I'm trying to use this **wonderful** git inside my xcode project:

https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data

It's fully functional when creating a new empty sqlite db.

But, how can I use an existing populated regular database?
I need to encrypt my sqlite file and use with the class provided from the git.

Thanks to all!

Comment: In general, SqlCipher (at least the iOS version) does not support encrypting an existing, "loaded" database.  You need to dump and reload your DB -- not a terribly difficult task.

Comment: @HotLicks negative answers are answers as well, maybe post this as an answer with - preferably - some data to back it up? With my inexperienced eye (regarding SQL) I could find little on the home page of the project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the SQLCipher convenience function [`sqlcipher_export`](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export).  In particular, look at example number 1 for a plaintext migration.

Comment: Thanks @Nick!
I tried this before and with success. The only strange thing after this way was a NSPredicates malfunction: Xcode doesn't recognize relates fields in queries. I don't know if this type of export can damage, in such way, the database structure.